# The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available VBA runtime error

Tags: vba

I'm getting this runtime error 2147483638 from excel vba code editor. I'm trying to send to my web service xml string and get a response back from the web service. Seems like it errors out because the response is "". Here's my code:

```
...... 
OutboundDocument.LoadXML (XMLServiceString)
On Error GoTo DoThisAgain
    XMLHTTPClient.Open "POST", WebServiceURL, False
    XMLHTTPClient.Send (OutboundDocument)
   'errors out here

DoThisAgain:
    serviceResponse = XMLHTTPClient.ResponseText ' equals "" gets error
```

Comment: Did you wait to receive the data? These call are not synchronous.

Comment: it works 8 out of 10 times.

Comment: Maybe the server respond fast enough 8 out of 10 times

Comment: Never mind, you passed false as third param to `open` . It should be synchronous

Comment: yes, that's what i thought too but it still errors out so i'm clueless as to why it's doing this.

Comment: Whats the _exact_ error?

Comment: runtime error 2147483638

Comment: Could there be an error while sending? what is the return value for `XMLHTTPClient.Send (OutboundDocument)`?

Comment: it is just a xml string formatted loaded to a object to send to the web.

Comment: I meant the return value of `.Send` not `OutboundDocument` if you write `result = XMLHTTPClient.Send(OutboundDocument)` what is the value of `result` ?

Comment: i can't output that to a variable.

Comment: Why? did you forget to declare it?

Comment: OutboundDocument is a variant / object seems like the result is ""

Comment: Sorry, i checked the wrond doc. `.send`returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This can avoid the error:

```html
Dim MyRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
With MyRequest
    .Open "GET", <URL>
    .send ""
    MyResponse = MyRequest.responseText
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

XMLHTTPClient.Open "POST", WebServiceURL, False

change above to true and make it synchronous (waits for response back before continuing)

Comment: I don't think so Sabina. The 3rd parameter is "ASync", so True would be ASYNCHRONOUS whereas what most folks want, I believe, is SYNCHRONOUS, therefore False. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757849(v=vs.85)